# How to remove focus from wpf window like in close event?

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I want to remove focus from my wpf window and set the focus back to the last "windows window" like it happens when I close a normal wpf window.

My WPF Window works like a layer over a normal "Windows Window". I just dont want to lose focus each time I click something on my "layer WPF Windows".

My workaround idea is that I set the focus back to the last "Windows Window" with my Button_Click Event Method.

Hope you can help me, because I was not able to find anything about this uncommon problem on the internet.

Comment: That's handled by the OS, not WPF. I don't think you can do that without closing the window, or resorting to WinAPIs

Comment: I added more information. Maybe there is a workaround for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get your hands dirty with P/Invoke. We'll need these functions from WinAPI:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint wCmd);
const uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
```

How to use them:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the WPF window handle
    IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;

    // Look for next visible window in Z order
    IntPtr hNext = hWnd;
    do
        hNext = GetWindow(hNext, GW_HWNDNEXT);
    while (!IsWindowVisible(hNext));

    // Bring the window to foreground
    SetForegroundWindow(hNext);
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in there.  I think you want `hNext = GetWindow(hNext, GW_HWNDNEXT);`.

Comment: @Joulukuusi It works fine and helped me alot. The problem is it doesn't work when my WPF Window is set to TopMost (as I want it to use as a layer). I tried the `SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab)` method and i have the same problem. It works when my window is not TopMost.

Comment: @AntiStoopMode, you should not use `SwitchToThisWindow`, because `This function is not intended for general use. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows` (quote from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633553.aspx). One possible workaround would be setting `TopMost = false` in the beginning of `Button_Click`, and restoring it to `true` in `Window.GotFocus` event.

Comment: @Joulukuusi Thanks alot! With setting the `TopMost = false` and activated it later again it works the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is minimizing the window.
This will give focus to the "last windows window".

```
window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want just give the focus back and let the window opened.